# Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^3$. Show the equivalence: $f^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $k=0,1,2 \iff \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be  $C^3$. Show the equivalence:

$$f^{(k)}(0) = 0 \quad k=0,1,2 \iff \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} \text{, exists.}$$

Trying:

Since $f \in C^3$, implies $f, f', f''$ are differentiable (therefore continuous) and $f'''$ is continuous in all domain.

Therefore we can approach $f$ with a order 3 Taylor polynomial, such as:

$$f(a+x) = f(a) + f'(a)x + \frac{f''(a)}{2}x^2 + r(x)$$

Where $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r(x)}{x^3} = 0$. *(can I assume that? isn't what I'm trying to prove? This is the definition of Infinitesimal Taylor Polynomial. ).*

$(\Rightarrow)$ Let's solve for $r(x)$

$$ r(x) = f(a+x) - f(a) - f'(a)x - \frac{f''(a)}{2}x^2 $$

Dividing by $x^3$

$$ \frac{r(x)}{x^3} = \frac{f(a+x)}{x^3} - \frac{f(a)}{x^3} - \frac{f'(a)}{x^3}x - \frac{f''(a)}{2x^3}x^2 $$

Lets take $a=0$

$$ \frac{r(x)}{x^3} = \frac{f(x)}{x^3} - \frac{f(0)}{x^3} - \frac{f'(0)}{x^3}x - \frac{f''(0)}{2x^3}x^2 $$

By hypothesis $f^{(k)}(0) = 0 \quad k=0,1,2$. Let's substitute:

$$ \frac{r(x)}{x^3} = \frac{f(x)}{x^3} - \frac{0}{x^3} - \frac{0}{x^3}x - \frac{0}{2x^3}x^2 $$

Taking the limit
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r(x)}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} - \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x^3} - \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x^3}x - \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{2x^3}x^2 $$

Since $f$ is continuous

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r(x)}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} - 0 - 0 - 0 $$

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r(x)}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} $$

Therefore $ r(x) = f(x) $ since the limit of $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r(x)}{x^3} $ exists (is a Taylor Poly) we conclude that lim of $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} $ also exists.

Is that correct? Also I don't have any idea in how to do the other direction.

Comment: The second-order Taylor polynomial only satisfies $\lim_{x\to 0} r(x)/x^2 = 0$, not $r(x)/x^3 \to 0$.  However, since you are told that $f$ is $C^3$ you can expand one more term.  You may not know the value of $f'''(0)$ but you are assured that it exists.

Comment: I tried to expand as you correctly stated, but I finished with:

$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{r(x)}{x^3} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^3} - \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'''(x)}{6x^3}x^3 $.

Can I assume that the last term goes to 0? ( I think I cannot since I dont know if f(x) is limited)

Comment: No, the last term does not approach zero.  But you must have made a mistake somewhere, it should be $f'''(0)$ in the numerator.  Also, the LHS does go to $0$ now because $r(x)$ is the remainder of a third-degree Taylor expansion.

Comment: Do any of these answers address the opposite direction's proof?

Comment: @ErickWong, and again. You're right. If should be $f'''(0)$ not $'''f(x)$. And since it goes to zero implies $\frac{f(x)}{x^3}$ is equal to $\frac{f'''(0)}{6x^3} x^3$ when $x \to 0$

Answer (score 2):

**METHOD 1:** Use L'Hospital's Rule

L'Hospital's Rule states that if the limit

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'''(x)}{1}$$

exists and $\lim_{x\to 0}f''(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$, then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f''(x)}{x}= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'''(x)}{1}$$

Since we are given that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'''(x)}{1}$ exists, along with $\lim_{x\to 0}f''(x)=0$, and it is trivially true that $\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$, then we have recursively

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)}{6x}=\frac16\lim_{x\to0}f'''(x)$$

and thus, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}$ exists.

---

**METHOD 2:** Use the extension of the mean value theorem

If you would rather use the [Extended Mean Value Theorem, or Taylor's Formula with a Remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem), then we know that there exists a $\xi$, $0<\xi<x$, such that

$$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12 f''(0)x^2+\frac16 f'''(\xi)x^3$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac16 f'''(\xi)=\frac16 f'''(0)$$

which exists by hypothesis. Note that the last equality is obvious from the continuity of $f'''$.

However, as pointed out by @ErickWong, there is a stronger form of Taylor's Theorem with a Remainder attributed to Peano, that states if $f, f', cdots ,f^{(k)}$ exist at a point $x_0$, then there is a function $R_k$ such that

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac12 f''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2+\cdots + f^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k+R_k(x)(x-x_0)^k$$

and thus $f/x^3\to \frac16f'''(0)$ even if $f'''$ is not continuous at $0$
with $\lim_{x\to x_0}R_k(x)=0$.

Comment: The appeal to continuity of $f'''$ can be avoided in showing that $f(x)/x^3 \to \tfrac16 f'''(0)$, which can be deduced from just existence of $f'''$, much like $f(x)/x \to f'(0)$ when $f(0) = 0$.  (I guess this makes Taylor's theorem a bit more powerful than MVT for a fixed level of differentiability?)

Comment: @ErickWong You are correct.  +1 for the suggestion.  I'll re-edit.

Comment: @ErickWong I re-edited and reference you for the suggestion.  I hope that you don't mind.

Comment: By all means, you're welcome to :).  Thanks for the credit.

Comment: You're certainly welcome and thank you for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Taylor remainder theorem: for each $x > 0$ there exists $0 < c < x$ with the property that $$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0) x + \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + \frac{f'''(c)}{6} x^3.$$ The stated hypotheses imply that $$\frac{f(x)}{x^3} = \frac{f'''(c)}{6}.$$ Write $c = c_x$ to emphasize the dependence on $x$. The definition of the limit and continuity of $f'''$ imply that $$\lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{f'''(c_x)}{6} = \frac{f'''(0)}{6}.$$ Thus $$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f'''(x)}{x^3} = \frac{f'''(0)}{6}.$$ The proof for the left-sided limit is nearly identical.

Comment: You don't really need continuity of $f'''$ if you express the remainder in "Peano form".

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: Suppose $g\in C^2(\mathbb {R})$ and $g'''(0)$ exists. If $0=g(0)=g'(0)=g''(0)=g'''(0),$ then $g(x) = o(x^3)$ as $x\to 0.$ Proof:

$$g(x) = g(x)-g(0) = g'(c_x)x = (g'(c_x)-g'(0))x= g''(d_x)c_xx= (g''(d_x)-g''(0))c_xx = [(g''(d_x)-g''(0))/d_x]d_xc_xx$$

where we've used the MVT twice. Since $c_x,d_x$ are in between $0$ and $x,$ and the term in brackets $\to g'''(0)=0,$ we see the above is $o(x^3)$ as desired.

Now consider an arbirary $f\in C^2$ such that $f'''(0)$ exists. Let $P(x) = f(0)+f'(0)x + f''(0)x^2/2 + f'''(0)x^3/3!.$ Then by the lemma,

$$f(x) = P(x) + o(x^3).$$

The conclusion in this problem for $f$ follows easily.